# Why is my code returning 'nan' using pandas while calculating a percentage?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

HW problem: Consider this investment strategy: buy whenever the price goes above the 50-day moving average, and then sell after 3 trading sessions. How much profit (in %) would we make on average? On trading day x, we say that the price "goes above" the 50-day moving average if (1) the price was below the moving average on trading day x-1 and (2) the price is above the moving average on trading day x.

```
rol=stock.rolling(50).mean()

profitMade=((stock.shift(-3)-stock)/stock)

stock>rol

profitMade[(stock<stock.shift(-1))&(stock>rol)]

profitMade.pct_change()

profitMade[profitMade.pct_change()].mean()
```

The last line returns 'nan' was expecting one value

sample data:

```
Date
2002-05-23      1.196429
2002-05-24      1.210000
2002-05-28      1.157143
2002-05-29      1.103571
2002-05-30      1.071429
2002-05-31      1.076429
2002-06-03      1.128571
2002-06-04      1.117857
2002-06-05      1.147143
2002-06-06      1.182143
2002-06-07      1.118571
2002-06-10      1.156429
2002-06-11      1.153571
2002-06-12      1.092857
2002-06-13      1.082857
2002-06-14      0.986429
2002-06-17      0.922143
2002-06-18      0.910714
2002-06-19      0.951429
2002-06-20      0.957143
2002-06-21      0.979286
2002-06-24      0.978571
2002-06-25      0.964286
2002-06-26      0.988571
2002-06-27      0.943571
2002-06-28      0.999286
2002-07-01      1.027857
2002-07-02      1.172857
2002-07-03      1.214286
2002-07-05      1.276429
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your data?

Comment: Are you looking for the average of the percent change? I think it should be ```profitMade.pct_change().mean()```

Comment: @kerwei I just tried the suggestion solution and got the same answer: 'nan' ? seems strange

Comment: @HenryWoody just added my sample data as well.

Comment: It's uncear what you're planing to do here: `profitMade[profitMade.pct_change()].mean()`, please clarify this point

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `rol` value, it's all of NaN's -

```
rol = stock.rolling(50).mean()
rol
Out:                                        
                               value                   
Date                                
2002-05-23                       NaN
2002-05-24                       NaN
2002-05-28                       NaN
2002-05-29                       NaN
2002-05-30                       NaN
2002-05-31                       NaN
2002-06-03                       NaN
2002-06-04                       NaN
2002-06-05                       NaN
2002-06-06                       NaN
2002-06-07                       NaN
2002-06-10                       NaN
2002-06-11                       NaN
2002-06-12                       NaN
2002-06-13                       NaN
2002-06-14                       NaN
2002-06-17                       NaN
2002-06-18                       NaN
2002-06-19                       NaN
2002-06-20                       NaN
2002-06-21                       NaN
2002-06-24                       NaN
2002-06-25                       NaN
2002-06-26                       NaN
2002-06-27                       NaN
2002-06-28                       NaN
2002-07-01                       NaN
2002-07-02                       NaN
2002-07-03                       NaN
2002-07-05                       NaN
```

When you do rolling, it uses a window of size, that case, 50, which captures values. By default, on the edge window captures less values than required, and fill it with `NaN`'s/ In your case, the size of the window much bigger than the size of DataFrame - so, all the values are set to NaN

To prove the concept, look at the smaller window size:

```
rol = stock.rolling(20).mean()
print(rol)
Out:
            value                   
Date                                
2002-05-23                       NaN
2002-05-24                       NaN
2002-05-28                       NaN
2002-05-29                       NaN
2002-05-30                       NaN
2002-05-31                       NaN
2002-06-03                       NaN
2002-06-04                       NaN
2002-06-05                       NaN
2002-06-06                       NaN
2002-06-07                       NaN
2002-06-10                       NaN
2002-06-11                       NaN
2002-06-12                       NaN
2002-06-13                       NaN
2002-06-14                       NaN
2002-06-17                       NaN
2002-06-18                       NaN
2002-06-19                       NaN
2002-06-20                  1.086143
2002-06-21                  1.075286
2002-06-24                  1.063714
2002-06-25                  1.054071
2002-06-26                  1.048321
2002-06-27                  1.041929
2002-06-28                  1.038071
2002-07-01                  1.033036
2002-07-02                  1.035786
2002-07-03                  1.039143
2002-07-05                  1.043857
```

- first non-NaN value is exaclty twentieth.

To avoid this behaviour, you can provide a value to the `min_period` argument of `rolling`:

```
rol = stock.rolling(50, min_periods=1).mean()
print(rol)
Out:
            value                   
Date                                
2002-05-23                  1.196429
2002-05-24                  1.203215
2002-05-28                  1.187857
2002-05-29                  1.166786
2002-05-30                  1.147714
2002-05-31                  1.135834
2002-06-03                  1.134796
2002-06-04                  1.132679
2002-06-05                  1.134286
2002-06-06                  1.139072
2002-06-07                  1.137208
2002-06-10                  1.138810
2002-06-11                  1.139945
2002-06-12                  1.136582
2002-06-13                  1.133000
2002-06-14                  1.123839
2002-06-17                  1.111975
2002-06-18                  1.100794
2002-06-19                  1.092932
2002-06-20                  1.086143
2002-06-21                  1.081054
2002-06-24                  1.076396
2002-06-25                  1.071522
2002-06-26                  1.068065
2002-06-27                  1.063086
2002-06-28                  1.060632
2002-07-01                  1.059418
2002-07-02                  1.063469
2002-07-03                  1.068670
2002-07-05                  1.075595
```

- so, if there are lesser elements than the window size, rolling works with provided amount of it.

Documentation about `min_periods`:

> min_periods : int, default None
>       Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value
>       (otherwise result is NA). For a window that is specified by an offset,
>       this will default to 1.

At the following line, you "loose" three last values setting them to NaN:

```
profitMade = ((stock.shift(-3) - stock)/stock)
profitMade
Out:
...
2002-07-01  1.276429
2002-07-02  NaN
2002-07-03  NaN
2002-07-05  NaN
```

- so, I guess, you shoul drop it (may be I'm wrong because this specific task is not so familiar to me). Then reindex `stock` and `rol` because you need the same size for the furthe operations.

```
profitMade  = profitMade.dropna()
stock = stock.loc[profitMade.index]
rol = rol.loc[profitMade.index]
```

Ok, there are three tables of equal size. I change the line which returns a table full of NaN's

```
profitMade[(stock<stock.shift(-1))&(stock>rol)]
Out:
               value
Date                
2002-05-23       NaN
2002-05-24       NaN
2002-05-28       NaN
2002-05-29       NaN
2002-05-30       NaN
2002-05-31       NaN
2002-06-03       NaN
2002-06-04       NaN
2002-06-05  0.008095
2002-06-06       NaN
2002-06-07       NaN
2002-06-10       NaN
```

to the

```
profitMade[(stock['value'] < stock['value'].shift(-1)) & (stock['value'] > rol['value'])]
Out:
    value
Date    
2002-06-05  0.008095
```

- it processes a specific column and drops NaN's.

Also, I can't get the idea what you are doing here:

```
profitMade[profitMade.pct_change()].mean()
```

- `profitMade.pct_change()` returns a table of `float` values (percent cahnge virtualy), but `profitMade[...]` expects a boolean object to work with - you should clarify and edit your question.

Full code:

```
rol = stock.rolling(50, min_periods=1).mean()
profitMade = ((stock.shift(-3)-stock)/stock).dropna()
rol = rol.loc[profitMade.index]
stock = stock.loc[profitMade.index]

profitMade[(stock['value'] < stock['value'].shift(-1)) & (stock['value'] > rol['value'])]
Out:
               value
Date                
2002-06-05  0.008095
```